# Django Python arrange json into a single node

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm working with a legacy database which has 2 records, the data in each record contain the following values: Name, Email, Company, Phone

These 2 records contain the same data value except the value for Phone which is different.

When I retrieve them in JSON I get the following output:

```
"results": [
        {
            "Name": "Mack",
            "Email": "Mack@email.com",
            "Company": "Company Name",
            "Phone": "123456789"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Mack",
            "Email": "Mack@email.com",
            "Company": "Company Name",
            "Phone": "1111111"
        }
    ]
```

My question: As you can see there is some duplicate data in the output above, so is there a way to arrange the JSON output to the following:

```
"results": [
        {
            "Name": "Mack",
            "Email": "Mack@email.com",
            "Company": "Company Name",
            "Phone": "123456789"
            "Phone 2": "1111111"
        }
    ]
```

Here is the code for Views.py file:

```
class DataView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DataList.objects.all()

    serializer_class = DataSerializer
```

Here is the code for Serializers.py file:

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data_details = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = DataList
        fields = 'data_details'

    def get_data_details(self, obj):
        return [{
            'name': obj.name,
            'email': obj.email,
            'company': obj.company,
            'phone': obj.phone,

        }]
```

Here is the code for models.py file:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_column='name', primary_key=True, max_length=50)  
    email = models.CharField(db_column='email', max_length=50)
    company = models.CharField(db_column='company', max_length=100)
    phone= models.TextField(db_column='phone')  

    class Meta:
        managed = False 
        db_table = 'data_table'
```

Thank you.

Comment: When should the merge take place?  If there are any duplicate names, or if the are duplicate names and emails, or only if there are duplicates of name, email and company?

Comment: You may want to look into the `dict.update()` function. However, this would replace your phone value, so you'd have to make sure your keys have different names if you use it.

Comment: Hi @CalebGoodman, the duplicate data will happen all the time, so if possible merge immediately

Comment: Hi @JammyDodger, i'm still new in Django, so may I know where can I use it? in which file?